# C# string character is equal, but equal condition return false

Tags: c#

Here's part of the data from my SQL table:

[image: SQL data]

When I fetch data show me like below

[image: c# show]

But when I use equal condition, it returns false

[image]

I check ASCII code and I am confused because it is different.

this.NameOfComm :

[image]

"doc" :

[image]

Comment: `&#65348;` is `U+FF44` is https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FF44 - which is not ASCII `D`.

Comment: In your screenshot one is full width ＤＯＣ and the other is half width DOC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look very closely, you will note that, in your first screenshot, the `DOC` in the first line has a slightly different font than the one in the second line.

- One of them contains the regular ASCII characters `D` `O` `C` , whereas
- the other one contains the [fullwidth forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms) `Ｄ` `Ｏ` `Ｃ` from the Unicode block U+FF00–FFEF. These are special forms of the Latin characters used to align nicely with Chinese/Japanese/Korean characters.

*(In addition, the fullwidth form characters seem to be HTML encoded, but that might be an artifact of your analysis.)*

---

You can use [`string.Normalize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=net-6.0#system-string-normalize(system-text-normalizationform)) to "fix" this:

```
// prints DOC
Console.WriteLine("ＤＯＣ".Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC));
```